# Should i use a mobile theme or responsive theme for my fashion store?

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, responsive, themes

I have a fashion store, then I decide to buy a new theme for my store. I am wondering whether to buy a mobile theme or responsive theme.

I know a mobile theme is more fast loading and simple than responsive theme. But you can open a responsive theme in mobile, tablet... Responsive theme can be compatible on all devices, but a mobile theme is only compatible on mobile, with others, it's not fit for much. Both of them are SEO friendly.

Can anyone advise me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme itself shouldn't impact performance that much, unless you're using drastically more fancyness (alphatransparency, animated state changes) in the responsive style than in the mobile one.

The biggest speed issue you'll have might be image size. This depends on what you're building towards, of course, but a fullscreen mobile photo can get away with being 500x500 pixels, but on a PC you should scale that to 1000x1000, or in other words, 4 times as many pixels.

But as Bob Sinclar already mentioned: test it. If you can figure out the rendering speeds of the mobile vs responsive, you'll be much closer to deciding which one suits your project best.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like webpagetest to see how much faster.

Speed does help online sales I remember hearing at a conference that Walmart found for every 100 ms they shaved off their page load time they saw a 1% increase in online sales.

Me personally my thought is to go with the responsive to not alienate tablet users unless the performance difference is night and day with mobile vs responsive . But without some hard data I would doubt it's that significant especially to effect your user experience and I would want a theme to cater towards all devices.

Also grab more data how many of your users currently are coming from tablets?

How terrible does the mobile theme look on resolutions between a mobile and a desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I have purchased themes and worked on an app before.
The issue is themes comes with heavy css and other supporting files. Many of these style we wont be even using in our app still we are forcing the user download all the supporting files. Refactoring this is a hell of a job.
Loading all these files in mobile having a slow network is bad experience. So use lighter css and js framework.

We received complaints from users about the performance.Now we have came up with a dedicated mobile app. A mobile app may not suite for your requirement if your users are not ready install the app or there is not so frequent usage.

So if mobile app is not appropriate for your use case then make sure that you are not keeping unwanted in your css or js files.